# How to compare CSV in db table field to the variable which also contain comma seperated values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have MySQL DB table `tbl_users`, which has two `uid`, `name`, `usergroupid`.  `usergroupid` contains the comma separated integers (IE: 1,2,3).

I want all the users which contain the user group ids say 1or 2 or 3 or 1,2 or 2,3 or 3,1 or 1,2,3. I am getting the value to compare in database from a variable which itself contains the comma separated values say, 1.2.3 or 1,2 or 2,3 or 3,1 or 1,2,3. Now what would be the select query to fetch the result.

I am using below select query to find the result but its wrong.

```
SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname 
  FROM tbl_users 
 WHERE user_group_id IN (".$usergroupid.")
```

here `$usergroupid` is the variable which contains the CSVs

Comment: Is the field in the MySQL table of type `varchar`???

Comment: The you can use pattern matching with `LIKE` right.  ie `user_group_id LIKE (%".$usergroupid."%)`

Comment: Can you change the database schema? Storing CSV in a column gives me nightmares.

Comment: That Means we need loop the $usergroupid to compare isnt it?

Comment: ya.. But when it is `varchar`, i think it is necessary.

Comment: Change your representation of the data so that it's not using comma-separated lists, or be prepared for a miserable time querying the data!

Comment: @Balanivash Could You Please add you Answering Comment in Answer section so that I Can Rate it

Comment: @Will A  and @ mu is too short, the time is here.. I cant5 change it now, my complete system is working on this, I Have to follow this

Comment: I think the best thing for something like this is having another table `usergroup` with `user` and `group` fields which will be a mapping from user to group. So in this case you can just do `SELECT userID FROM usergroup WHERE groupid IN $usergroupid`

Comment: You really should have a separate table that ties uid to usergroupid. It will make so much more sense.

Comment: To further improve the poor design and modelling, you can dynamically generate a set of **LIKE's** for each of the values on your list and then compare them later using an IN statement. Top notch performance. @mu is too short will freak out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do in this situation is to use pattern matching to find the required values.

```
SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname  FROM tbl_users WHERE user_group_id LIKE (%".$usergroupid."%)
```

This is if you want the exact pattern in the csv, else you have to break your csv according based on `,` and run it in a loop to get the desired result.

But i think the best thing for something like this is having another table `usergroup` with `user` and `group` fields which will be a mapping from user to group. So in this case you can just do

```
SELECT userID FROM usergroup WHERE groupid IN $usergroupid
```

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` has the potential to pick up on completely the wrong usergroup if you do LIKE '%1%' then if you've a group 10, 11, 12 etc. it'll match.

*Assuming* that all of your strings are of the form x,y,z,... then a less naive `LIKE` would be more robust.

```
SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname
FROM tbl_users
WHERE (',' + user_group_id + ',') LIKE '%,".$usergroupid.",%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `FIND_IN_SET`? I've been using it sometimes and it works pretty well in those cases.

```php
"FIND_IN_SET(user_group_id,".$user_group_id".)"
```

Some more info: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)